# SQL Subquery using IN Statment with coalesce

Tags: sql, subquery, coalesce, sql-in

I have the following SELECT statmentment

```
SELECT
       UserID
      ,UserName
      ,TradingParty
      ,Email
      ,[PrivDesc]
      ,LastLogin
      ,IsApproved

FROM
    cte_getAll allUsers
 WHERE
      allUsers.TradingParty                                            = COALESCE(@TradingParty, allUsers.TradingParty)
    AND allUsers.Username                                      = COALESCE(@Username, allUsers.Username) 
    AND allUsers.Email                                       = COALESCE(@EmailAddress, allUsers.Email)
    AND DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, allUsers.[LastLogin]), 0)   >= COALESCE(@FromDate, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, allUsers.[LastLogin]), 0)) 
    AND DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, allUsers.[LastLogin]), 0)   <= COALESCE(  @ToDate, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, allUsers.[LastLogin]), 0))
    AND allUsers.IsApproved                                   = COALESCE(@AccountActive, allUsers.IsApproved)
      AND allUsers.[PrivId]                                        -- IN (SELECT privId from @selectedPriv)
                                                                      IN (COALESCE((SELECT PrivID FROM @selectedPriv), allUsers.[PrivId]))
```

**EDIT**
Prior to this statment i am populating the @selectedPriv temp table according to the users input. If there is not user input therefore the table will contain nothin

On the final AND statement i am trying to find all data where privId is equal to a list of privs which the user has entered. So for example the user eneters 1,2,3,4,5,6 that is stored into a temp table, from this i need to find all the rows from my original table which are associated with these priv. 
Here is my issue if i use the commented IN statement it works but since the user is allowed to pass in NULL i need it within a COALESCE, but when i do this i get the message

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

I havent got a clue on why this is. Any ideas that will help me fix this issue?

Comment: I'm not understanding the `NULL` handling - are you wanting to limit the results to only the `@selectedPriv` values if they passed in data, and show everything if they passed in `NULL`?

Comment: @Siyual - yes that is fairly standard interface -- null defaults to all.

Comment: I'm guessing you are populating a temp table called @selectedPriv prior to this statement -- is that correct?

Comment: Can you just do your `Coalesce()` inside of your subquery? It makes no sense to do a `Coalesce()` outside like that.

Comment: Do the COALESCE inside the subquery, not the opposite.

Comment: Guys he can't do the coalesce in the sub-query -- there are NO rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a table variable that has values that you want to select from, but if they don't have any values in the table, you don't want the restriction at all.

The reason you're getting the error you're getting is due to `COALESCE()` only expecting a single value to transform, but your query is returning multiple.

This may be what you're looking for:

```
 AND 
 (
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @selectedPriv WHERE PrivID IS NOT NULL)
    OR
    (
            EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @selectedPriv WHERE PrivID IS NOT NULL) 
        AND allUsers.[PrivId] IN (SELECT PrivID FROM @selectedPriv)
    )
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are populating the temp table @selectedPriv prior to this statement just add an else there -- if the input is null have @selectedPriv =

```
SELECT DISTINCT PrivId FROM cte_getAll
```

This should be faster than a more complicated where statement that checks count(*) in @selectedPriv which is the other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

COALESCE can only take one value for it's first argument, which is why it complains when you get more than one value from that query.  You could switch that part for something a bit different using some ANDs and ORs.  (Note: untested, but should at least be close.)

```
AND (((select count(*) from @selectedPriv) = 0)
    OR ((select count(*) from @selectedPriv) != 0 AND allUsers.[PrivId] IN (SELECT privId from @selectedPriv)))
```

Answer (score 0):

coalesce works fine but you can use ORs instead and that might help you with your last AND.

```
SELECT
    UserID,
    UserName,
    TradingParty,
    Email,
    [PrivDesc],
    LastLogin,
    IsApproved
FROM
    cte_getAll allUsers
WHERE
    allUsers.TradingParty = COALESCE(@TradingParty,allUsers.TradingParty)
    AND (@Username IS NULL OR allUsers.Username = @Username)

    AND (@EmailAddress IS NULL OR allUsers.Email = @EmailAddress)
    AND (@FromDate IS NULL OR DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,allUsers.[LastLogin]),0) >= @FromDate)
    AND (@ToDate IS NULL OR DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,allUsers.[LastLogin]),0) <= @ToDate)
    AND (@AccountActive IS NULL OR allUsers.IsApproved = @AccountActive)
    AND (@PrivIDS IS NULL OR allUsers.[PrivId] IN (SELECT PrivID FROM @selectedPriv))
```